# How to make valet point to localhost:8000 not to htdocs for laravel freamwork

Tags: laravel, xampp, localhost, laravel-5, laravel-valet

I am using Windows 10 and I have set up Valet for my Laravel 5.2 project using 'php artisan serve' that sets up the server on localhost:8000 . When I am using XAMPP (for apache and MySQL) and go to localhost it is all fine. When I go to localhost:8000 still all works. But when I go to my_project_name.dev it goes to localhost. And when I try with some_random_name.dev it goes to localhost again. But in my htdocs I have a few projects and I would like to make it like it should be : my_project_name.dev to point to my_project_name directory. Or if that is not possible atleast my_project_name.dev should point to localhost:8000 .

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Laravel Valet only supports Mac

Answer (score 0):

You must enable mode_rewrite on apache
1) open the `httpd.conf`
2) Find the following line `#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` in the `httpd.conf` file.You can do this easily by searching the keyword `mod_rewrite` from find menu.
3) Remove the `#` at the starting of the line, `#` represents that line is commented.
4) Now restart the apache server.

Comment: It has been the same as it should be. The line you have told me was uncommented. If that helps with Laragon is the same situation